# How to incorporate an extract statment into mathematical operations?

Tags: postgresql, math, extract, amazon-redshift

I have to do simple subtraction of time but need help implementing two queries into one script.

Due to some internal restrictions on DB, I can not convert timestamp column too time using any of the methods in postgresql. Instead I used "extract" to pull out the hour, minute, seconds, and rejoin them into one column.

**My question is how do I combine the extract statement and a mathematical function statment I wrote that subtracts time from the second cell right below it and adds either the word "min" or "sec" if the time is subtracted from minute or seconds, if this is not possible then no worries**. . Example:

```
table A
  time          new_time(logic) 
0 4:50:55       time(1) - time(0) = 1sec
1 $:50:56       time(2) - time(1)
```

Extract statement:

```
select (extract(hour from timestamp) || ':' || extract(minute from timestamp) || ':' || extract(second from timestamp)) as my_time 
from tableA
```

Mathematical statement:

```
update page
set time= timestamp
from (
    select tableA.timestamp - lead(tableA.timestamp) over (order by time) 
    from tableA
    ) 
where tableA.id = tableB.id
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you cast the timestamp to time?: `select now()::time`

Comment: Your line works but it does not work when I try to cast the whole date/timestamp column to time.

Comment: What do you mean by _whole date/timestamp column_?

Comment: So there is one column that holds the date/timestamp, I need to convert that whole column into just time. Your above script does not work when I try to implement it on the full column. hope this makes sense

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: this is what I ran 'select now(timestamp)::time from tableA'

error I got: 

SQL Error [500310] [42883]: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: function now(timestamp without time zone) does not exist;

Comment: just use `timestamp::time` to cast your `timestamp` column to a `time` (btw: `timestamp` is a horrible name for a column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update page
set time = timestamp
from (
    select id,
        lead(timestamp::time) - timestamp::time over (order by timestamp::time) 
    from tableA
) tableA
where tableA.id = page.id
```

Comment: For some reason I can not cast timestamp to time and i get the error I posted above. SQL Error [500310] [0A000]: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.

I did some digging and the column that holds timestamp is listed as "timestamp without time zone" do you think that could be why I am not able to cast or convert to time?

Thanks for helping

Comment: I found details about the table using this line:

select * from pg_table_def where tablename = 'tableA'

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.